# Microservice API implementation with two databases

Tags: transactions, microservices

I am working on building a microservice that uses MongoDB as the "metadata" database and S3 for file storage. One of the APIs of the microservice requires updating both, the S3 and MongoDB, in the same API call.

As a scenario, let us say the API is:

POST /tickets

- Updates S3 with ticket documents (i.e. there is a single folder in which two documents are created: a pdf ticket for sending over email and an image for sharing over email)
- Updates a MongoDB table with ticket status, i.e. ticket has been booked.

I understand that ticket booking is usually a complex affair with multiple microservices involved but for our theoretical scenario, let us say that only one microservice is sufficient. Ticket API runs some computation and decides to book the ticket by updating S3 database and MongoDB.

The question is: How should I maintain content integrity between the two databases?

Based on general reading, for distributed transactions across microservices, it is recommended to use either 2PC or some event pattern like SAGA. I understand the need to go to the level of complexity for "transactions" across microservices. But is the same solution applicable if a single microservice is maintaining content in two databases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a correction that that 2PC is highly discouraged in microservices architecture so SAGA is preferred practice. You can find more here [SAGA](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html)

**Current Architecture**

A single API can talk to multiple data sources . Think Data sources just other APIs so there is no problem single API talking to multiple APIs.

Regarding data integrity in multiple data sources is your responsibility . SAGA does exactly the same. Multiple local transactions in distributed services make up complete transaction and if something goes wrong in any of the local transaction we raise compensating transaction instructing all other services to undo if they have already committed the local transaction. That's how we keep data consistent across services.

In your case you are responsible to commit in S3 and then mongo DB later or vice versa. And if anything is wrong  you have to revert or take pervasive measures (Compensating transaction) to keep both the data sources sync. Since you are doing both operations in single API so it's easier for you to maintain consistency.

**Tip**: This architecture is good but may not scale well. If your business case allows You can consider using queues and trigger lambda to go serverless. In future other services can also use the same message if you are using queues.

Hope that Helps!